# postfix recursive custom operator in swift

Tags: ios, swift, operator-overloading

I'm trying to declare a custom postfix operator that calculates the factorial of a given number, is there a way to make this function recursive (number-1)!!?

```
postfix operator !! {}
postfix func !! (number: Double) -> Double {

    if (number <= 1) { return 1.0 }
    return number * (number-1)!!

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is impossible simply because it conflicts with the `!` which is used for unwrapping optionals.

From [The Swift Programming Language: Keywords and Puncutation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/postfix-operator)

> The following tokens are reserved as punctuation and can’t be used as custom operators: `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `.`, `,`, `:`, `;`, `=`, `@`, `#`, `&` (as a prefix operator), `->`, `` ` ``, `?`, ***and `!` (as a postfix operator)***.

However, in my opinion, if this is the case then it's a bug that `postfix operator !! {}` is valid. I'd recommend [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

You could get around this by using `‼` for example (Double exclamation mark; U+203C).

Comment: i've reported it to apple, by the way thank you for the detailed answer +1 :D

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, but not if you use `!!`- it interprets it as two implicit optional deferences. Some other symbol will work - e.g:

```
postfix operator £ {}
postfix func £(number : Double) -> Double {
  if number<=1 {
    return 1.0
  }
  return number * (number-1)£
}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have an idea why this works, but € is not allowed? I get "'€' is considered to be an identifier, not an operator".

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify postfix operator on file level:

```
import UIKit

postfix operator !
struct A {
    var a = 5
    var b = 10

}

extension A {

    static postfix func !(m: A) -> A {
        return A(a: -m.a, b: -m.b)
    }

}

var obj1 = A(a:45, b: 46)
var obj4 = obj1!
```

Now, obj4 values will be -45, -46